# How can i prevent the open files tab bar from wrapping changing number of rows when toggling between horizontally split editors

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

Sometimes the number of rows in my "open files tab bar" changes when going from one side of my split editor setup to the other:

[image]

This is really annoying and I have no idea why this happens as I don't see no the size change of the individual tabs. Only the font color of the selected tabs etc. changes. I'm not sure what actually changes (could be color, weight, ...) but I don't think that this should cause a layout shift.

I'm using the color theme [Atom One Dark](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akamud.vscode-theme-onedark) with quite a few adjustments via the settings file.

Is this something I can fix on my own by adjusting some theme settings or is this a general UX issue in VSCode for which I should create a feature request?

## Update

I just disabled all my customizations to `Atom One Dark` and am still experiencing the same behavior. This also happens when switching to some other theme like `GitHub light default` so it doesn't seem to be caused by the theme itself.

Could this be caused by some other setting etc?

Comment: why does the `records.hive.d.ts` tab take so much space when the group gets focus

Comment: @rioV8 I think there's some setting which makes the tabs "take up all space" when multi lines are used. However, I was just looking for that setting but did not find it anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that this is not caused by some change in the tab sizes but because of the additional context menu at the right side of the tab bar which is only shown for the active side:

[image]

Those buttons can be hidden via right click. I just hid all of them which solved the issue for me.